# How to search for words starting with or contained within a certain word

Tags: java

I am trying to see if `foo` contains "inactive" or if the user is trying to type portions of the word "inactive".

**Is there a simpler way to achieve this?**

```
if (foo.equals("inactive") || foo.equals("inactiv")
                || foo.equals("inacti") || foo.equals("inact")
                || foo.equals("inac") || fofoo.equals("ina")
                || foo.equals("in") || foo.equals("nactive")
                || foo.equals("nactiv") || foo.equals("nacti")
                || foo.equals("nact") || foo.equals("nac")
                || foo.equals("na") || foo.equals("n")) {
```

Comment: better to use regex.

Comment: How about `ac`? Does it work too? If not what is the rule to decide if the input is valid?

Comment: doesn't "inactive".contains(foo) work for you?

Comment: Use StringUtils.contains (...)
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 5):

Try using this

```
if ("inactive".indexOf(foo) != -1)
{
    System.out.println("Contains!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Originally I thought that what you want is `if( foo.indexOf( "inactive" ) != -1 )`.  But I am wrong.  And all answers are wrong.  Because what you want is impossible.  (Sorry, it was very late night when I was writing my original answer.)

In set theory, every set also contains the empty set. From this it follows that *every* string contains a portion of the word "inactive", because:

- the empty string is also a portion of the word "inactive", and
- every string contains the empty string.

So, @assylias has captured the essence of the problem in his comment to the OP.

One of two things is true: either

- you have not thought very well what you want to accomplish, or
- you have not explained very well what it is that you want to accomplish.

As it stands, your question cannot receive any answer other than `if( true )`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.contains("nact");
```

This is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains(CharSequence)` and `startsWith(String)` methods defined in `String` class.

See more information in official documentation.

- [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))
- [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 1):

If it means it should match if any character used in "inactive" string is part of foo.

You can use regular expression [inactve], it will match foo if foo contains any of the characters mentioned in the regular expression. i is omitted from inactive in regular expression as it is coming twice.

See this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) for more details.